# Not able to filter few columns in magento admin grid

Tags: magento2, grid, filter

I am not able filter few columns like sku in my custom module.Other columns are working.

```
<column name="sku">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

for this column filter is not working.Can any one suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: <column name="sku">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
     <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
     <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item>
     <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
    </item>
   </argument>
  </column>

Comment: For this column filter is not working i have given type as text in schema. This is the error getting            
 {error: "UI component could not be rendered because of system exception", errorcode: "23000"}

Comment: add your full xml.

Comment: Not able to add full xml